# how to show db value in time type input box?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Want to show previous data on the edit Page.

I'm trying this

```
<input type="time" name="opening_hour" value="{{ old('opening_hour', $restaurants->opening_hour) }}" class="form-control">
```

in Database, the opening_hour field is time type. value is 10:00:00

but when I try to show in time type input field it getting an error
**array_key_exists(): The first argument should be either a string or an integer**

What should I do in laravel blade?

Comment: I think the error is very clear, it seems like `$resturants->opening_hour` is an object. You need to parse it to time string

Comment: kindly give me a solution to parse this to time ```$restaurant->opening_hour```

Comment: i have no problem with the old() i faced error in ```$restaurant->opening_hour``` it didn't showing in input value which type is "time".

Comment: it shows ```"10:00:00"```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235843/discussion-between-tariqul-anik-and-porloscerros-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found my solutions. it will be `date('H:i', strtotime($restaurants->opening_hour))` inside value.